# How to intercept network traffic in multiple memu emulators?

Tags: android, emulation, tcpdump

I have multiple memu (android emulator) instances (called for example emu1, emu2, emu3, etc...),
multiple instances of the same opened app in this emulators (app1, app2, app3, etc...) and I want to save the intercepted traffic in 3 different folders (folder1, folder2, folder3, etc...) with tcpdump.

In this moment I'm using:

1) Windows 7

2) Tcpdump for windows (fork of native tcpdump)

3) Memu

I can change at any moment OS and emulator if this solves my problem.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can capture from each emulator individually in a fairly straightforward way. Install https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=app.greyshirts.sslcapture&hl=en on each device by downloading the apk and installing it u
sing ADB. You can then proceed to run this app on each emulator and log the traffic. It has an option to save to a file.